# Error when trying to call Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: oracle, powershell, odp.net

The following error is logged when I try to call Fill(), and my powershell session crashes.

> Event Type:   Error Event Source: .NET Runtime Description: .NET Runtime
>   version 2.0.50727.3625 - Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

My script looks like:

```
$asm = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Oracle.DataAccess”) 
$userName = "foo"
$tnsDbName = "bar"
$pass = "foobar"
$connectionString = "User Id=$userName;Password=$pass;Data Source=$tnsDbName"

$q = @"
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE blar = '5848752'
"@

$cstr = $connectionString 
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($cstr)
$conn.open()
$adapter = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($q,$conn)
$dataset = New-Object Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)
$dataset.Tables[0]
```

If I only run up through the "$adapter =" line to see the state of things before a crash I have:

```
PS H:\> $asm.GetName()

Version        Name                                                                                         
-------        ----                                                                                         
10.2.0.100     Oracle.DataAccess  

PS H:\> $adapter.SelectCommand.Connection | fl ClientID,ConnectionTimeout,ServerVersion,State


ClientId          : 
ConnectionTimeout : 15
ServerVersion     : 10.2.0.4.0
State             : Open
```

I'm open to suggestions!   There MAY have been an update to the ODP.NET done on my computer, but all other applications that use it (some simple winform apps) and Toad for Oracle are working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?  [An access violation occurs when you run a .NET Framework 2.0-based application that has a virtual call the IList, IEnumerable, or ICollection interface in an LCG (Lightweight Code Generation) method.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971030) A DataSet does implement IListSource that has a method GetList() which returns an IList which implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Can you add some details about where this is applies please?

Comment: As the KB article says, it seems that in some circumstances, you get the error you mention (and there is a patch for it). If you look at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter in Reflector, you'll see that it uses IListSource quite a lot. Might help you to check that KB and apply the patch. Or might not.

Comment: Work machine - I can't load the hotfix.  And I don't have reflector :(.  If I'm going to get traction on any support tickets for a hotfix, I will sadly have to take more to them than "Might... Or might not." :(